# Behavior of Functional Interface and Method Reference

Tags: java, generics, java-8, functional-interface

What happens when the reference of a method which belongs to a variable is destroyed?

```
public class Hey{
    public double bar;

    public Hey(){
        bar = 2.0d;
    }

    public double square(double num){
        return Math.pow(num , bar);
    }
}

Function<Double, Double> square;
whatsGonnaHappen: {
    Hey hey = new Hey();
    square = hey::square;
}//is hey still kept around because its method is being referenced?

double ans = square.apply(23d);
```

Comment: have you tried calling a method after square? Why would it be gone?

Comment: What functional interface are you referring to, btw?

Comment: The `Function` interface located in java.util.function @Stultuske

Comment: How would `square.apply(23d)` work if the `Hey` instance was garbage collected?

Comment: The only thing that's happening is a refusal to compile.  Could you provide an example that compiles and can pose the same question?

Comment: You don’t need to deal with scopes at all: `DoubleUnaryOperator square = new Hey()::square;` creates a function bearing a reference to an instance of `Hey` to which no other references exist. Of course, that instance will not cease to exist, as that’s the whole point of a programming language with memory management; you can’t destroy an object that is still in use.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Scope is a compile time concept that governs where names in source code can be used. [From the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3)

> The scope of a declaration is the region of the program within which
>   the entity declared by the declaration can be referred to using a
>   simple name, provided it is visible (§6.4.1).

The fact that the name `hey` is restricted to the body of the `whatsGonnaHappen` labeled statement doesn't have any bearing on whether the instance referenced by `hey` at runtime is a candidate for garbage collection (which I assume is what you're worried about).

Concerning the variable capture, yes, the method reference `hey::square` is a reference to an instance method of a particular object (the one referenced by `hey`) and will therefore capture the value of the variable `hey` when the method reference expression is evaluated to produce an instance and use it when `apply` is invoked.

Answer (score 2):

Your method reference is essentially equivalent to doing this:

```
Hey hey = new Hey();
Function<Double, Double> square = new DoubleDoubleFunction(hey);
```

where the class `DoubleDoubleFunction` is defined like this

```
class DoubleDoubleFunction implements Function<Double, Double> {
    private final Hey hey;

    public DoubleDoubleFunction(Hey hey) {
        this.hey = hey;
    }

    @Override
    public Double apply(Double num) {
        return hey.square(num);
    }
}
```

In other words, `square` holds a reference to the `Hey`.

I don't know about eclipse, but with IntelliJ you can easily translate method references and lambdas into anonymous / static nested / inner classes to see what's going on. I find this a very instructive thing to do.

Comment: You can do that [in Eclipse](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2FwhatsNew%2Fjdt_whatsnew.html) too, thanks for the discovery!